# How to import SwipeRefreshLayout color scheme from XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, swiperefreshlayout

I know how to set SwipeLayout spinner colors programatically, using 
.setColorSchemeResources().

How can I do this by passing a .xml file instead ?

```
swipeToRefreshSpinner.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
```

Comment: Can you precise what you want to achieve? Is it about using other colors that the given ones or about setting it up another way?

Comment: It's about setting it up another way. Suppose I have more spinners throughout my app, instead of setting their colors dynamically every time, I wanna pass a .xml file so in the future if I decide to change colors I only have do it once.

Comment: I think theres no way to do this through `style.xml` or other attributes. The only way would be to set up own colors in the `colors.xml` and using them like `swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.customNamedColor);`. That way you'd use custom colors and if you give all `SwipeRefreshLayouts` these custom colors, you'd only have to change the colors in `colors.xml` to change it for all Spinners at once.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you make that a formal answer so I can select it ?

Comment: Of course, I'm glad if that was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change all colors at a central point you can define custom colors in your `colors.xml`. If you give all your `SwipeRefreshLayouts` these colors, they can be changed at once. 
You can define a color like this:

```
<color name="customNamedColor">#FFFFFF</color>
```

and use it just like you already did but referenced to your own color:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.customNamedColor);
```